# Pgfplots heatmap: specify z column

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My data file looks like this:

```
1.3622 -2 0.0794479 0.00652291
1.36215 -2 0.0685207 0.00482894
1.3621 -2 0.0600571 0.00370146
1.36205 -2 0.0534619 0.00300152
1.362 -2 0.0479574 0.00248143

1.3622 -1.95 0.0797369 0.00674456
1.36215 -1.95 0.0686836 0.00499037
1.3621 -1.95 0.0601782 0.00382963
1.36205 -1.95 0.0535552 0.00310782
1.362 -1.95 0.0480346 0.00257176

.
.
.
```

etc.

Here's my code for a heatmap plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}    
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      colorbar,
      view={0}{90},]
      \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {surfTest.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

I want to plot this as a heatmap with \addplot3, but I want the **fourth column** to be the z values. I tried `file[z index = 3]` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does `\addplot3[surf, shader=interp] table[z index = 3] {surfTest.txt};`, i.e. `table` instead of `file`, give you what you want?

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer! And yes, that did the trick. So I suppose `file` is just a shortcut for `table` that automatically selects the first three columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a quick experiment:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{surfTest.txt}
1.3622 -2 0.0794479 0.00652291
1.36215 -2 0.0685207 0.00482894
1.3621 -2 0.0600571 0.00370146
1.36205 -2 0.0534619 0.00300152
1.362 -2 0.0479574 0.00248143

1.3622 -1.95 0.0797369 0.00674456
1.36215 -1.95 0.0686836 0.00499037
1.3621 -1.95 0.0601782 0.00382963
1.36205 -1.95 0.0535552 0.00310782
1.362 -1.95 0.0480346 0.00257176
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[at={(0,0)},title={table},
      colorbar,
      view={0}{90},]
      \addplot3[surf, shader=flat] table {surfTest.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[at={(3,0)},title={table[z index=3]},
      colorbar,
      view={0}{90},]
      \addplot3[surf, shader=flat] table[z index = 3] {surfTest.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[at={(0,-64)},title={file},
      colorbar,
      view={0}{90},]
      \addplot3[surf, shader=flat] file {surfTest.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[at={(3,-64)},title={file[z index=3]},
      colorbar,
      view={0}{90},]
      \addplot3[surf, shader=flat] file[z index = 3] {surfTest.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the outputs are always the same except for `table[z index = 3]`. I do not precisely know what `file` does because I am never using it (and I did not come across this syntax in the manual very often either), but IMHO this strongly suggests that you may want to use the `table` syntax.